# pycharm remote debugging: failed to find free socket

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, ubuntu-14.04, remote-debugging, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to use remote debugging but get this error on pycharm:

**Error running remoteTest:
failed to find free socket**

My remote host is Ubuntu |(with username and password) and my localhost is windows, I followed the following tutorial:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2010/12/python-remote-debug-with-pycharm/
and I used a ssh tunnel on putty to connect to the server.

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=21000, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

Comment: I have same issue, but with Ruby remote debug. My remote is vagrant ubuntu box and it seems that this issue is common to all JB IDE's. Did you figured it out?

Comment: try this :
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/deployment.html

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?